# how to send bulk mail using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create mailing function like gmail and yahoo,  where we can enter multiple id in to,cc,bcc fiels to send  multiple mails but not able to do so. I can send single mail with attchment on only one mail id,but not to multiple mail ids in to ,cc ,bcc.  I am using texboxes to add mail ids

Can any one help me.

Comment: Having multiple recipients isn't exactly bulk mail. In any case, I think PHPMailer can do this.

Comment: Hi now I able to send mail to multiple id but when i try to send mail only to one id it shows error,and when I enter email id's to all field then only mails will deliver.  Can any one suggest me some thing.  code is     $strTo= $_POST["too"];

$cc= $_POST["ccc"]; 

$bcc=$_POST["bc"];


$strSubject = $_POST["subj"];  
$strMessage = $_POST["message"];  
  
//*** Uniqid Session ***//  
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));  
  
$strHeader = "";  
$strHeader .= "Cc: ".$cc."\r\n";
$strHeader .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";

$strHeader .= "from: Buzinessworld <service@buzinessworld.com>";

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of 'Bulk'. If you're talking 100s of emails, you should use a batched mail sender as advised on [php.net/mail](http://php.net/mail). There are a few PHP options but I'd suggest something that will allow you to do background processing so as to not hold up your script.

If you're just doing this for a few recipients, you can inject `Bcc` and `Cc` headers into your email message when using `mail(..)`. There are full examples on the php.net page linked above.

A (copied from documentation) example is below:

```
<?php

$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  .. snip
</body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```